# NumPY: Undestand how to sum every n values in an array matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi folks,

```
 array([[  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
            ...
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.]
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.],
           [  3.,  12.,  21.,  30.]])
```

How to sum every 29 rows in the same column:
(3+3+3+3...) 29times. 
Could be great to reshape the size of our array (1392, 8760) in a (48, 8760) after the sum of these values.
I tried to look at the reshape and sum function but I am having a hard time to deeply understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea here is to add an additional dimension to your array to break it into `n` length chunks, then sum along the first axis.

***Setup***

```
a = np.zeros((1392, 8760))
chunk_size = 29
```

Using **`reshape`** and **`sum`**:

```
out = a.reshape(-1, chunk_size, a.shape[1]).sum(1)
print(out.shape)
```

```
(48, 8760)
```